# SwiftUI on MacOS App - strange Focus behavior

Tags: macos, swiftui, focus

I have this little example app, that works as expected.
The Textfields an the YellowTextfield get the focus in the expected order.

If I add a **.cornerRadius(5.0)** th the Textfield of YellowTextfield, the focusorder changes.
Now the YellowTextfield gets the focus on start.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent this?

```
struct TestFocusOrder: View {
  @State var name = ""
  @State var age = ""
  @State var city = ""
  @State var job = ""

  var eyeColors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Tartan"]
  @State private var eyeColor = ""

  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      TextField("Name", text: $name)
      YellowTextField(title: "yellow field", text: $city)
      TextField("age", text: $age)
      Picker("eye color", selection: $eyeColor) {
        ForEach(eyeColors, id: \.self) {
          Text($0)
        }
      }
      Text("\(name) age:\(age) eye color:\(eyeColor)").font(.footnote)
    } .frame(width: 400, height: 400, alignment: .center)
  }
}

struct YellowTextField: View {
  var title: String
  @Binding var text : String

  var body: some View {
    TextField(title, text: $text)
      //.cornerRadius(5.0).   // <== Uncomment this, then the focus order changes
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `.cornerRadius(5.0)` does not round corners of `TextField` in `MacOs` like it could in `iOS`

Try this:

```
TextField(title, text: $text)
.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle()) // <-- rounded
```

For greater customization  something like:

```swift
TextField(title, text: $text)
.padding()
.overlay(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
    .stroke(Color.blue, lineWidth: 1)
)
```

Comment: Tnx!  Any idea, why the focuskorder is changed?

Comment: Because, in my opinion, it is not the right way to round the corners and this leads to abnormal behavior. With `.cornerRadius (5.0)` nothing changes in MacOS: the corners are not rounded, so you don't need to use it. With the examples above, the corners are rounded and the behavior is correct